# i have trouble making a discord.py lyrics finder bot

Tags: discord.py

pls help me find a code that works

this code I wrote edosent work as well

````
async def lyrics(self, ctx, artist,*, title):
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
           async with session.get(f"https://api.lyrics.ovh/v1/{artist}/{title}") as response:
                data = await response.json()
                lyrics = data['lyrics']
                if lyrics is None:
                    await ctx.send("Song not found! Please enter correct Artist and Song title")
                if len(lyrics) > 2048:
                     lyrics = lyrics[:2048]
                emb = discord.Embed(title = f"{title}" , description = f"{lyrics}")
                await ctx.send(embed=emb)
        await session.close()```
````

Comment: Please read this: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please take a look:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: ;-; thats sad to hear